# Графический ключ в своем приложении

Tags: java, activity, android

Существует ли стандартный механизм андроид для использования графического пароля? Как на картинке: [image: Пример графического ключа]
Или же необходимо самому реализовывать?

Я хочу использовать его в приложении вместо стандартного пароля (ввожу логин, нажимаю, например, кнопку "авторизоваться" -> ввожу ключ -> получаю его код -> авторизовываюсь на сервере).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартного контрола для графического пароля нет.

Можете попробовать [android-lockpattern](http://haibison.github.io/android-lockpattern/) ([демо](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.demo)).